# React router - How to get rid of # in url

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-v4

how do I get rid of '#' in url while using react router? 
If i redirect a link to "example.com/user". it goes to "example.com#/user". I need to remove the '#' in the url.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to use a `BrowserRouter` instead of a `HashRouter`

Comment: In addition of `BrowserRouter` You have also to provide a .htaccess if want your routing does not conflict with serverside routing

Comment: I changed the BrowserRouter instead of HashRouter. Now, its working

Comment: I am facing other issue now. After, i clicked the login button, only the URL changing in the browser URL tab, But the page not loading(i.e its not taking to the next page).

Answer (score 1):

Where you define your routes replace

```
<HashRouter> with <BrowserRouter>
```